# How to read two lines from file at a time and split into two variables?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```py
file = open("codecipherinput.txt", "r")

while True:
    line1 = file.readline()
    line2 = file.readline()
    #print(line1 + line2)
    if not line2: break  # EOF
    currentline = line1 + line2

for i in range(3):
    print(currentline)
    s, text = currentline.strip().split(" ")

def encrypt(text, s):
    result = ""

    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]

        if char.isupper():
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 65) % 26 + 65)

        else:
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)

    return result


#text = input("Enter Word: ")
#s = int(input("Shift: "))
print("Cipher: " + encrypt(text, s))
```

These are the contents of my file:

```
7 
rmpc is the best! 
3 
i’m loving it 
23 
there’s nothing more fun than comp-sci programming
```

I am trying to have the program take two lines at a time from the file and split those lines into two variables but am unsure how. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`, and it happens automatically:

```
for line1, line2 in zip(file, file):
    ...
```

`zip` pulls from the first iterable, then from the second (except they're the same here, so it's just two lines), and then we unpack the resulting `tuple` to named variables. `zip` stops when either iterable is exhausted, matching the `if not line2: break` code implicitly.

Comment: I don't have much experience with zip() or tuples in general so I am probably going to need a bit more hand holding to understand this. Is there just a way to use the typical split()?

Comment: @zhtb: You said you wanted two lines in separate variables, which this does. If you meant to parse apart those lines in some other way, you need to be more specific.

Comment: As I said, this solution could be perfect for me and I wouldn't be the wiser. I was hoping to just be able to use the split() function. It's fine if you can't help.

Comment: @zhtb: I mean, you can always do silly things like shove the two lines together then split them apart, e.g. `for combined in map(operator.concat, file, file): x, y = combined.split()`, but it's extremely unclear why you would want to.